# Proposition 17.11 - Tu's Introduction to Manifolds

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

Trying to prove the following proposition which is left as exercise:

> **Proposition 17.11 : (Pullback of a sum and a product)**. Let $F : N \to M$ be a $C^{\infty}$ map of manifolds. Suppose $\omega, \tau \in \Omega^1(M)$ and $g \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Then
>
> (1) $F^*(\omega + \tau) = F^* \omega + F^* \tau$
>
> (2) $F^*(g\omega) = (F^* g) (F^* \omega)$

I managed to prove (1) I think, but I can't manage to prove (2) despite the clue given by the textbook.

For (1):
Let $X_{p} \in T_p(N)$
$$
F^*(\omega + \tau)(X_p) = (\omega + \tau)(F_* X_p) = \omega(F_* X_p) + \tau(F_* X_p) = (F^*\omega)(X_p) + (F^*\tau)(X_p)
$$

So both LHS and RHS act in the same way on a vector.

For (2): I've tried a similar approach

$$
F^*(g\omega)(X_p) = g\omega(F_*X_p)
$$

But I'm not sure what to do from here

Can you help? I'm sure it's probably simple, but I can't figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to write the pullback definition more explicitly. If $\omega$ is a smooth $1$-form on $M$ and $F:N \to M$ is smooth, then $F^*{\omega}$ is a $1$-form defined by: for all $p \in N$ and all $X_p \in T_pN$,
\begin{align}
(F^*\omega)(p)(X_p) &:= \omega(F(p))[F_{*,p} X_p]
\end{align}

I believe you're having issues because you havent indicated where the forms are being evaluated. Recall that since $\omega$ is a one-form on $M$ it assigns to each point $q \in M$, an element $\omega(q) \in T^*_qM$. So, you first have to evaluate a one-form at a point of the manifold, and after that apply the whole thing to a tangent vector; the final result being a real number.

So, for all $p \in N$ and all $X_p \in T_pN$, we have
\begin{align}
\bigg(F^*(g \omega)(p) \bigg)(X_p) &:= \bigg((g \omega)(F(p)) \bigg)[F_{*,p} X_p]  \\
&:= \bigg(g(F(p)) \cdot \omega(F(p)) \bigg) [F_{*,p} X_p] \\
&:= g(F(p)) \cdot \bigg( \omega(F(p))[F_{*,p} X_p]\bigg)  \\
&:= (F^*g)(p) \cdot (F^*\omega)(p)[X_p] \\
&:= \bigg( (F^*g)(p) \cdot (F^*\omega)(p) \bigg)[X_p] \\
&:= \bigg( \left( F^*g \cdot F^* \omega \right) (p) \bigg)[X_p]
\end{align}
Thus, it follows that $F^*(g \omega) = F^*g \cdot F^* \omega$. I'll leave it to you to figure out why I put in so many equal signs. Each of them is true either by definition of pullback $^*$, or by definition of product of a function and form, or by definition of scalar multiplication in the cotangent space $T_{F(p)}^*M$ etc. Hopefully the bracketing makes it clearer what is being evaluated on what (although for convenience, I may have dropped some brackets).

Comment: I confess I'm doing this exercise to make sure I understand the definition of pullback. I'm not quite sure about the equality $$\bigg((g \omega)(F(p)) \bigg)[F_{*,p} X_p] = \bigg(g(F(p)) \cdot \omega(F(p)) \bigg) [F_{*,p} X_p]$$
More specifically about the bit
$$\bigg((g \omega)(F(p)) \bigg) = \bigg(g(F(p)) \cdot \omega(F(p)) \bigg)$$

Comment: In general if $g \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ then the product $g \omega$ is defined by $(g\omega)(q) = g(q) \cdot \omega(q)$ for all $q \in M$. Note that on the RHS, $g(q)$ is a number, and $\omega(q)$ is an element of the vector space $T_q^*M$, hence the scalar multiplication $g(q) \cdot \omega(q)$ is already well-defined. This is what we're using to DEFINE $g \omega$. I simply applied this logic when $q$ is the particular point $F(p) \in M$.

Comment: @user8469759 when in doubt, always go back to definitions, and see where each object is defined, what kinds of objects are being added or multiplied (forms/vectors/numbers/functions etc)

Comment: Hi, one queston. In your chain of equalities can you explain why do we have: $$\bigg(g(F(p)) \cdot \omega(F(p)) \bigg) [F_{*,p} X_p] = g(F(p)) \cdot \bigg( \omega(F(p))[F_{*,p} X_p]\bigg) $$?

Comment: @user8469759 that's by definition of scalar multiplication in the cotangent space $T_{F(p) }^*M$. to convince yourself of this fact, ask yourself what kind of object is $g(F(p)) $ and what kind of object is $\omega(F(p)) $ etc

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking of (scalar multiplication in cotangent space), just double checking.